# How do I get these arrays to be equal to each other?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I'm cleaning up a game of tic-tac-toe I made a while back because I'm bored but I ran into a problem. The items are different because whenever I use .push or .splice on them it adds "" around the numbers. Can anyone help me fix this?

```js
const winningCombos = ["123", "456", "789"];
const myCombos = [];
myCombos.splice(0, 0, "2");
console.log(myCombos);
myCombos.splice(0, 0, "1");
console.log(myCombos);
myCombos.push("3");
console.log(myCombos);
if (winningCombos[0] === myCombos[0]) {
  console.log("Success")
} else {
  console.log("Fail")
}
```

All I want it to do is it to end with the console saying Success and the numbers being equal to 123. Can anybody help me?

Comment: It's not adding the quotes. They're in the argument to `splice()`.

Comment: So remove the quotes and just have the numbers?

Comment: If you want the result to be `["123"]` rather than `["1", "2", "3"]` you should be concatenating strings rather than splicing.

Comment: Wow thanks that looks like it will work. Also thank you for all the help you give! I feel like I always see your name in the comments or with an answer!

Comment: This looks like you're trying to implement tic-tac-toe. So why don't you have `X` and `O` in your arrays?

Comment: It was just an example I don't really know why I didn't do that now that I think about it...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want `myCombos` to be an array similar to `winningCombos`, you shouldn't be splicing and pushing onto it. You should concatenate to the individual strings in the array.

```js
const winningCombos = ["123", "456", "789"];
const myCombos = ["", "", ""];
myCombos[0] = "2";
console.log(myCombos);
myCombos[0] = "1" + myCombos[0];
console.log(myCombos);
myCombos[0] += "3"
console.log(myCombos);
if (winningCombos[0] === myCombos[0]) {
  console.log("Success")
} else {
  console.log("Fail")
}
```

As you can see, with strings it's not so easy to insert a new character in a specific place, because they're immutable. It would be easier if you used a 2-dimensional array.

```js
const winningCombos = [
  [1, 2, 3],
  [4, 5, 6],
  [7, 8, 9]
];
const myCombos = [
  [0, 0, 0],
  [0, 0, 0],
  [0, 0, 0]
];
myCombos[0][1] = 2;
console.log(myCombos);
myCombos[0][0] = 1;
console.log(myCombos);
myCombos[0][2] = 3;
console.log(myCombos);
if (arrays_equal(winningCombos[0], myCombos[0])) {
  console.log("Success")
} else {
  console.log("Fail")
}

function arrays_equal(a1, a2) {
  return a1.length == a2.length && a1.every((el, i) => el == a2[i]);
}
```

Comment: Wow thanks that's even better!

Comment: Yeah, but that gets even more complicated than the string stuff.

Comment: @MisterJojo But combining an existing value requires bit masking.

Comment: But you still need to mask: `myCombos[0] |= 1 << n`

Comment: And clearing is `myCombos[0] &= ~(1 << n)`

Comment: @MisterJojo Yeah, but I'm not going to use this answer to refactor the OP's general design.

Comment: I added my answer with boolean logic

Answer (score 0):

in the mind of a simple admirer of George Boole

```js
const player = (()=>
  {
  let binPos = 0;  
  const winningCombos =  // change this values in binary numbers
      ['123', '456', '789','159' , '753'] 
      .map(s=>[...s].reduce((n,x)=> n |=  1 << --x , 0))
  , add_Pos =p=> { binPos |= 1 << --p; }
  , is_Win  =_=> winningCombos.some(win => (win === (win & binPos)))
      ;
  return { add_Pos, is_Win }
  })();

// Let play!    

player.add_Pos(2);
player.add_Pos(3);
player.add_Pos(1);

console.log( player.is_Win() ) // true
```